# Map a NumPy array of strings to integers

Tags: python, arrays, string, performance, numpy

**Problem:**

Given an array of string data

```
dataSet = np.array(['kevin', 'greg', 'george', 'kevin'], dtype='U21'),
```

I would like a function that returns the indexed dataset

```
indexed_dataSet = np.array([0, 1, 2, 0], dtype='int')
```

and a lookup table

```
lookupTable = np.array(['kevin', 'greg', 'george'], dtype='U21')
```

such that

```
(lookupTable[indexed_dataSet] == dataSet).all()
```

is true. Note that the `indexed_dataSet` and `lookupTable` can both be permuted such that the above holds and that is fine (i.e. it is not necessary that the order of `lookupTable` is equivalent to the order of first appearance in `dataSet`).

**Slow Solution:**

I currently have the following slow solution

```
def indexDataSet(dataSet):
    """Returns the indexed dataSet and a lookup table
       Input:
           dataSet         : A length n numpy array to be indexed
       Output:
           indexed_dataSet : A length n numpy array containing values in {0, len(set(dataSet))-1}
           lookupTable     : A lookup table such that lookupTable[indexed_Dataset] = dataSet"""
    labels = set(dataSet)
    lookupTable = np.empty(len(labels), dtype='U21')
    indexed_dataSet = np.zeros(dataSet.size, dtype='int')
    count = -1
    for label in labels:
        count += 1
        indexed_dataSet[np.where(dataSet == label)] = count
        lookupTable[count] = label

    return indexed_dataSet, lookupTable
```

Is there a quicker way to do this? I feel like I am not using numpy to its full potential here.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with the `return_inverse` argument:

```
>>> lookupTable, indexed_dataSet = np.unique(dataSet, return_inverse=True)
>>> lookupTable
array(['george', 'greg', 'kevin'], 
      dtype='<U21')
>>> indexed_dataSet
array([2, 1, 0, 2])
```

If you like, you can reconstruct your original array from these two arrays:

```
>>> lookupTable[indexed_dataSet]
array(['kevin', 'greg', 'george', 'kevin'], 
      dtype='<U21')
```

If you use pandas, `lookupTable, indexed_dataSet = pd.factorize(dataSet)` will achieve the same thing (and potentially be more efficient for large arrays).

Comment: You've changed my life!

Answer (score 5):

[np.searchsorted](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) does the trick:

```
dataSet = np.array(['kevin', 'greg', 'george', 'kevin'], dtype='U21'), 
lut = np.sort(np.unique(dataSet))  # [u'george', u'greg', u'kevin']
ind = np.searchsorted(lut,dataSet) # array([[2, 1, 0, 2]])
```