# How to display a NumPy array of strings without quotes and with comma as a delimiter?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, genfromtxt

I am trying to generate an array out of a file with `numpy.genfromtxt`.

File is like:

```
16.37.235.200|59009|514|16.37.235.153|
17.37.235.200|59009|514|18.37.235.153|
```

And I get an array like:

```
['16.37.235.200' '17.37.235.200']
```

But I want the array to be like that:

```
[16.37.235.200,17.37.235.200]
```

Comment: IPs are 4 numbers separated by dots.  They can only be stored as strings, They aren't integers or floats,

Answer (score 5):

Here is your original array:

```
x = np.array(['16.37.235.200', '17.37.235.200'])
```

which is displayed like this when printed:

```
print(x)
>>> ['16.37.235.200' '17.37.235.200']
```

In order to display it with comma as a delimiter and without quotes around strings we can use [`np.array2string`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html):

```
print(np.array2string(x, separator=',', formatter={'str_kind': lambda x: x}))
>>> [16.37.235.200,17.37.235.200]
```

I don't like that `lambda x: x` formatter but couldn't come up with something better to remove the quotes.

---

You can find more here: [How to pretty-printing a numpy.array without scientific notation and with given precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/how-to-pretty-printing-a-numpy-array-without-scientific-notation-and-with-given)

Comment: Okay thank you, so i can use that to delete the quotes around the strings. Do u have a clue, how i map those IP adresses to a unique integer (injective function)?

Comment: @QWERASDFYXCV See here: [Map a NumPy array of strings to integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676576/map-a-numpy-array-of-strings-to-integers)

Comment: Ok thanks, but I have 2 arrays of strings filled with IP Adress (Source,Destination), and i want to map IP Adress A in both arrays to the same integer. Does np.unique(dataSet, return_index=True) work there also? I don't think it works, because they get the value dependent on their index.

Comment: @QWERASDFYXCV You should ask a separate question about this.

Comment: I did, at the moment im trying to get it work with np.unique(dataSet, return_inverse=True) but it gives me two arrays as return. But i just only need the array of the return_inverse. Do you know how i can get only that one array as return?